# How can I revert the last two commits on my mainline branch without issuing a change request (CR)?

Tags: git, github, commit

I accidentally committed two changes – let’s say `commit98`, `commit99` — to mainline. So now the mainline branch moved to `commit99` from `commmit97`

I wanted to revert the last two changes and put the mainline back to `commit97`.

Also I am not supposed to directly push code changes to the repository without a CR (change request).

So, I wanted the changes locally so that I can create a CR (change request).

Comment: Do you want to revert or hard reset?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new branch:

```
git checkout -b some_branch
```

Then:

```
git rebase -i the_first_commit_you_want_to_modify^
```

Then adjust the order of commit.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Do not rebase commits that have already been published to the "central" repository. Merging them through a CR will end up with the repository having *both* copies of the commits, original and edited.